# create a transaction for MS Access in c#

Tags: c#, ms-access

I need some code in my c# application to implement a transaction using Microsoft Access database

Comment: What is your question? What have you tried?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OleDbTransaction class is made just for that.  You can create one by calling BeginTransaction on your OleDbConnection object then Commit or Rollback up to your scenario

```
using (var transaction = cn.BeginTransaction()) {
  //Do Stuff here using the connection
  transaction.Commit();
}
```

The transaction will be rolled back at dispose if no commit has been called.

Answer (score 0):

Try to implement the code similar to the one below.

```
    public void InsertPersonAndPhoneNumber(int personId, string name, string phone)
    {
        string connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=./contacts.accdb";
        OleDbConnection cn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
        try
        {
            cn.Open();
            OleDbTransaction trans = cn.BeginTransaction();
            try
            {
                //first transaction ...
                string sql1 = "INSERT INTO People (ID, pname) VALUES (@ID, @pname)";
                OleDbCommand cmd1 = new OleDbCommand(sql1, cn, trans);
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", personId);
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pname", name);
                cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();

                //first transaction ...
                string sql2 = "INSERT INTO PhoneNumbers (PID, num) VALUES (@PID, @num)";
                OleDbCommand cmd2 = new OleDbCommand(sql2, cn, trans);
                cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PID", personId);
                cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@num", phone);
                cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();

                trans.Commit();
                Console.WriteLine("New Contact Added successfully ...");

            }
            catch (Exception x)
            {
                //handle exception .... 
                trans.Rollback();
                Console.WriteLine(x.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                cn.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception x)
        {
            //handle exception .... 

        }

    }
```

Comment: Hi Kingstone, thank you for contributing. You may want to edit your answer and address the code block formatting problem. Remove extra spaces (at the end and in the middle). Sometimes it's easier to past the code into Notepad, remove the extra stuff and then wrap it in triple `

Comment: @LanceMcCarthy You are correct that this needs cleaning up, but do keep in mind that Stack Overflow does not use triple fences for code blocks, instead it uses 4 spaces. Please advise using the `{}` button to make a proper code block.

Comment: @Ajean Acknowledged!