# Best way to insert data into multiple tables in access?

Tags: .net, ms-access, ms-access-2007

Okay so here is my database:

[image: http://i488.photobucket.com/albums/rr245/lolwtf_album/database.jpg]

I have a page on my .net form that lets users insert a workout and the related muscles for that workout into an access database.

Once I insert a record to the WorkOuts table, how do I insert the related muscles into the MuscleGroup table without having the select the max ID of the workout that was just inserted? I want to insert everything in together, at the same time.  Hopefully my question makes sense, I think this is a common database issue, but I haven't found a solution yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although I agree you should look into using alternate RDBM'S, you can use the following code (assumes you are using OLEDB and C#) to retrieve the correct AutoNumber generated by an MS-Access Insert statement:

```
public static object InsertRow_ReturnKey()
{
  try
  {
    using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection())
    {
      con.ConnectionString = Users.GetConnectionString();
      con.Open();
      OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
      cmd.Connection = con;
      cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
      cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO WorkOuts(Workout) VALUES('Abs')";
      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
      cmd.CommandText = "SELECT @@IDENTITY";
      return cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    }
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(ex.Message);
    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusCode = 500;
    return null;
  }
}
```

Call it by using:

```
int newID = (int)DB.InsertRow_ReturnKey();
```

Comment: I didn't know access had that feature.  This is good to know!

Comment: Cool. This code is for a web application, but can also be used with WinForms or WPF. Note that this technique can also be used with ADO and DAO.

Answer (score 1):

yes, this is very common, but it will require a minimum of 3 queries, if not more since it's access.

1. to insert the record
2. to retrieve the id
3. one for each muscle group (you *might* be able to combine these, but I doubt it)

Access is also a poor choice for a database as it lacks many of features enterprise level databases and ado.net support. Transactions being the biggest missing feature, and named parameters being the second.

if you need a "smaller" or free database solution check out SqlExpress, SqLite, or Posgress. Any of these will work since you are currently targeting Access.

Comment: Yeah the more i use access, the more i hate it.  I'll have to redo this in SQL.

Comment: really? because anytime i have read or seen a reference to Access and Ado.Net (or data access framework) these are first two problems devs run into.

Comment: @JasonMeckley See [Create a transaction for ms-asccess in c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4352590/create-a-transaction-for-ms-access-in-c-sharp) for transactions. Named parameters a more mixed bag. They're supported with QueryDefs. They're not with inline SQL. You have to use "?". I don't know if SQLLite or Progess supports that either but I've not played with it.