# MC Access transaction in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-access

Could this work to use transaction for methods? I got methods where they read/insert/update ms access.

```
using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(ConnectionString)) {

     OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
     cmd.CommandText = "BEGIN TRANSACTION";
     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    //C# code, methods etc where I put some values into db via OleDbCommand etc

     cmd.Parameters.Clear();
     cmd.CommandText = "COMMIT [TRANSACTION | WORK]";
     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

     //No idea what to put here.. 

     cmd.Parameters.Clear();
     cmd.CommandText = "ROLLBACK [TRANSACTION | WORK]";
     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

}
```

Comment: Have you looked into `conn.BeginTransaction()`? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4352590/create-a-transaction-for-ms-access-in-c-sharp

Comment: *"Could this work ..."* - Well, not literally, because `COMMIT [TRANSACTION | WORK]` is normal syntax notation for `COMMIT TRANSACTION` *or* `COMMIT WORK` (i.e., they are apparently synonyms). You could try one or the other and then [edit] your question to share your results.

Comment: Never mind. This is a duplicate question as @Brad pointed out.

Comment: @GordThompson Just checked that question. Inside where he wrote -> `//Do Stuff here using the connection`, do I have to relate those syntax with transaction or will everything automatically include in transaction in that field?

Comment: The `OleDbTransaction` is related to a specific instance of `OleDbConnection`, and any `OleDbCommand` objects using that `OleDbConnection` will also have to respect the `OleDbTransaction` once it has begun. That is why the `OleDbCommand` constructor has an [overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6ywwyhf(v=vs.90).aspx) that includes an `OleDbTransaction` parameter.