# Check if values in DataGridview are compatible with database table/schema BEFORE Inserting

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database, datagridview

I have a DatagridView which gets values from excel files. After the values are shown in the datagridview, the user can add/alter them and when the user presses save, my code inserts the table to my database. I have surrounded my code with try catch so it stops when there is an error because of the values but when the user corrects the data and presses save again, the first rows that have been inserted are inserted again to the database. My question is, how can i write a code so it doesn't duplicate the rows that it has inserted already? Thank you in  advance. My code that inserts is down below.

```
      try
        {

            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(commandText, cnn);

                Guid g = Guid.NewGuid();

                //veritabanına verileri atıyoruz
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@guidkodu", g);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@faturatarihi", belgetarihigetir((dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString()))); //datetime a cast ediliyor
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@faturano", (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value).ToString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@vkntckn", (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value).ToString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tur", (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value).ToString());

                //kdv değerleri yoksa veritabanına null,varsa değerini atıyoruz

                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty((dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value).ToString()))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@kdv0matrahi", System.DBNull.Value);
                }
                else
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@kdv0matrahi", ToNullableFloat((dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value).ToString()));
                }


                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty((dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value).ToString()))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@kdv1matrahi", System.DBNull.Value);
                }
                else
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@kdv1matrahi", ToNullableFloat((dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value).ToString()));
                }

                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty((dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value).ToString()))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@kdv1tutar", System.DBNull.Value);
                }
                else
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@kdv1tutar", ToNullableFloat((dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value).ToString()));
                }

                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty((dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[7].Value).ToString()))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@kdv8matrah", System.DBNull.Value);
                }
                else
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@kdv8matrah", ToNullableFloat((dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[7].Value).ToString()));
                }

                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty((dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[8].Value).ToString()))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@kdv8tutar", System.DBNull.Value);
                }
                else
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@kdv8tutar", ToNullableFloat((dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[8].Value).ToString()));
                }

                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty((dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[9].Value).ToString()))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@kdv18matrah", System.DBNull.Value);
                }
                else
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@kdv18matrah", ToNullableFloat((dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[9].Value).ToString()));
                }

                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty((dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[10].Value).ToString()))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@kdv18tutar", System.DBNull.Value);
                }
                else
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@kdv18tutar", ToNullableFloat((dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[10].Value).ToString()));
                }

                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty((dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[11].Value).ToString()))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@oiv", System.DBNull.Value);
                }
                else
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@oiv", ToNullableFloat((dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[11].Value).ToString()));
                }

                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty((dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[12].Value).ToString()))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@faturatutari", System.DBNull.Value);
                }
                else
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@faturatutari", ToNullableFloat((dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[12].Value).ToString()));
                }
                //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@islemtarihi", zaman);



                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();


            }

            MessageBox.Show("Veriler Kaydedildi");
            this.Hide();
            //GirisFormu a = new GirisFormu();
           // a.ShowDialog();

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            MessageBox.Show("bir hata oluştu, tekrar deneyiniz");
        }
```

Comment: Did you mean you want to have a checking between your table and your database? so that you wouldn't insert a duplicate record from your table to your database?

Comment: @Raynoceros Exactly. And I believe I'm getting somewhere with IF NOT EXISTS statement when inserting.

Comment: You can set your primary key in the database so that when trying to insert duplicate records, it will unable to do so and return back the **violation of primary key constraint error**

Comment: You can also read everything from your database again and store it in another table, check all the records by looping line by line, comparing the _ready-to-insert data_ with the table.

Comment: Why not to use transaction to avoid any unnecessary insert to database. You commit the data when of everything goes well, otherwise rollback the transaction. Look at this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4352590/create-a-transaction-for-ms-access-in-c-sharp

Comment: Don't use [addwithvalue](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/)

Comment: Stop coding and think about your GUI and how you expect user to work with it. Does user expect everything entered to be added to DB as a single, complete unit? Or does user expect each row to be added independently? Until you decide how you want user to interact with your app, this question cannot easily (or efficiently) answered.

Answer (score 0):

Declare a static variable count in your class and initialize it to 0

```
static int count=0;
```

Comments and changes highlighted by ***

```
try
        {

            for (int i = count; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)//***start the for loop by count***
            {
                OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(commandText, cnn);

                Guid g = Guid.NewGuid();

                //veritabanına verileri atıyoruz
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@guidkodu", g);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@faturatarihi", belgetarihigetir((dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString()))); //datetime a cast ediliyor
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@faturano", (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value).ToString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@vkntckn", (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value).ToString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tur", (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value).ToString());

                //kdv değerleri yoksa veritabanına null,varsa değerini atıyoruz

                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty((dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value).ToString()))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@kdv0matrahi", System.DBNull.Value);
                }
                else
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@kdv0matrahi", ToNullableFloat((dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value).ToString()));
                }


                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty((dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value).ToString()))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@kdv1matrahi", System.DBNull.Value);
                }
                else
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@kdv1matrahi", ToNullableFloat((dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value).ToString()));
                }

                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty((dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value).ToString()))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@kdv1tutar", System.DBNull.Value);
                }
                else
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@kdv1tutar", ToNullableFloat((dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value).ToString()));
                }

                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty((dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[7].Value).ToString()))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@kdv8matrah", System.DBNull.Value);
                }
                else
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@kdv8matrah", ToNullableFloat((dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[7].Value).ToString()));
                }

                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty((dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[8].Value).ToString()))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@kdv8tutar", System.DBNull.Value);
                }
                else
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@kdv8tutar", ToNullableFloat((dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[8].Value).ToString()));
                }

                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty((dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[9].Value).ToString()))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@kdv18matrah", System.DBNull.Value);
                }
                else
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@kdv18matrah", ToNullableFloat((dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[9].Value).ToString()));
                }

                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty((dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[10].Value).ToString()))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@kdv18tutar", System.DBNull.Value);
                }
                else
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@kdv18tutar", ToNullableFloat((dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[10].Value).ToString()));
                }

                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty((dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[11].Value).ToString()))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@oiv", System.DBNull.Value);
                }
                else
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@oiv", ToNullableFloat((dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[11].Value).ToString()));
                }

                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty((dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[12].Value).ToString()))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@faturatutari", System.DBNull.Value);
                }
                else
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@faturatutari", ToNullableFloat((dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[12].Value).ToString()));
                }
                //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@islemtarihi", zaman);



                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                count+=1;//***increment the count on every successful insert.***

            }

            MessageBox.Show("Veriler Kaydedildi");
            this.Hide();
            //GirisFormu a = new GirisFormu();
           // a.ShowDialog();

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            MessageBox.Show("bir hata oluştu, tekrar deneyiniz");
        }
```